# how to add Jquery script to one page?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

What is the best practice to apply an individual script to a particular page?  When I try to apply the script of the whole page it  has problems with other plug-ins.  Is there a rule of thumb?

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

(function() {

$('html').addClass('js');

var contactForm = {

    container: $('#contact'),

    config: {
        effect: 'slideToggle',
        speed: 500
    },

    init: function(config) {
        $.extend(this.config, config);

        $('<button></button>', {
            text: 'Contact Me'
        })
            .insertAfter( 'article:first' )
            .on( 'click', this.show );
    },

    show: function() {
        var cf = contactForm,
            container = cf.container,
            config = cf.config;

        if ( container.is(':hidden') ) {
            contactForm.close.call(container);
            container[config.effect](config.speed);
        }
    },

    close: function() {
        var $this = $(this), // #contact
            config = contactForm.config;

        if ( $this.find('span.close').length ) return;

        $('<span class=close>X</span>')
            .prependTo(this)
            .on('click', function() {
                // this = span
                $this[config.effect](config.speed);
            })
    }
};

contactForm.init({
    // effect: 'fadeToggle',
    speed: 300
});

})();

</script>
```

Comment: Is that for fron-end or back-end? And why do you use an outdated jQuery instead of the built-in version?

Comment: front end for a slider.  I'm working one tutorial that is a few months old and that is probably why I'm referencing the outdated J query version. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This url works
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
and for particular page you can use

```
if( is_page('x')) { ?>
// YOUR SCRIPT STUFF
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually register all the scripts I need using `wp_register_script` and then use `wp_enqueue_script` inside a conditional for scripts that need to be loaded only on specific pages.

**functions.php**

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'global', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/global.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'example', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/example.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'global' );

    if ( is_page( 2 ) ) { // example page
        wp_enqueue_script( 'example' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```